# how to remove keyboard before opening subview in swift 4?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have use bellow code for opening subview in swift 4. onClick textfield, Subview will open. But keyboard is not dismissed. I want to dismiss keyboard before opening the my subview. 
I have use bellow code to open subview..

```
 func btnWatisPlan() {
    let popUpVc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Category") as! Category
    self.addChildViewController(popUpVc)
    popUpVc.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popUpVc.view)
    popUpVc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

Here is my **textFieldDidBeginEditing** code & from textFieldDidBeginEditing I have called the subview Ontouch my textfield named **sp_whatis_for_plan**

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {        
    if (textField == sp_whatis_for_plan)
    {

       view.endEditing(true)
        btnWatisPlan();

    }
 }
```

Please help me..

Comment: try `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and return false when you want to open another view when texField is clicked

Comment: @kathayatnk i tried it but in vain

Answer (score 0):

You have two options can either **resign the first responder** or you can **call end editing** for the parent view.

**Resigning first responder**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {        
    if (textField == sp_whatis_for_plan){
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
        btnWatisPlan();
    }
 }
```

**To end editing**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {        
        if (textField == sp_whatis_for_plan) {
           self.view.resignFirstResponder()
           //Note: the view must be the view which contains the text field
           btnWatisPlan();
        }
     }
```

**

> If you simply want to launch a sub view very time the text field is
>   enabled you can add a `@IBAction` for the text field to touch up
>   inside and perform the same actions please refer the image  [Interface
>   builder for UITextField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thLRD.png)

**

Answer (score 0):

You are calling function after keyboard gets opened(didEndEditing). You should call your function before keyboard opens. User **textFieldShouldBeginEditing** which says whether you want to allow keyboard for particular text or not. Just return **false** for your textfield.

Please Try below code

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField == sp_whatis_for_plan
    {
        btnWatisPlan();
        return false  
    }
    return true  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

this code make your text field inactive, but you must not use it on Delegate method of UITextField

Answer (score 0):

I see there seems to be some problem due to addition of childController. If you end the editing in view with return false than I believe it will work, like below

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == sp_whatis_for_plan {
        btnWhatIsPlan()  //call the popup here
        view.endEditing(true) //end the editing on the view
        return false  //also return false
    }
    return true
}
```